# Copying content of C buffer to numpy array

Tags: python, c++, c, data-binding, cython

I have a function in C like this:

source file

```
// foo.cpp
int foo(int input1, double *output1, int size1, int* output2, int size2)
{
// does stuff and allocate space for output1 and output2
    return 0;
}
```

header file

```
// foo.h
int foo(int input1, double *output1, int size1, int* output2, int size2);
```

In Cython I need to convert `output1` and `output2` to a numpy array, so in my `foo.pyx` I do the following steps:

```
cdef extern from "foo.h":
    cdef int foo(int input1, double* output1, int size1, double* output2, int size2) 

cdef double* ptnOutput1
cdef int* ptnOutput2

foo(1, ptnOutput1, 10, ptnOutput2, 10)
```

but now I'm not able to get the output in form of two `np.array`. How should I align the pointers `ptnOutput1` and `ptnOutput2` to two numpy arrays?
I've tried `np.frombuffer` as well as `np.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData` but with no luck. I always get segmentation fault.
Any idea how to do it correctly?

Comment: Ignoring the Cython aspect of it for the moment, how would you call this in C? I'd have thought `ptnOutput1` and `ptnOutput2` need to already be allocated when you call `foo` (which then fills in their contents)?

Comment: http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html is a good description of how to work with arrays, cython native memoryviews and C arrays.

Answer (score 1):

The numpy documentation mentions that

> In order to make use of the C-API from another extension module, the `import_array` function must be called

It seems you got the segmentation fault error because you didn't include import_array in your code.

The internal machinery of `import_array` is more complex than what you may expect because it's actually a very lengthy macro, not a plain function. Refer to [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html?highlight=import_array#importing-the-api) for more information